# Inheriting French Property. Is it Possible From the US?

Tags: france

My mother, infirm and living in the US, wants to transfer ownership of property in France to me. What legal documents do I have to show French authorities to transfer that property into my name? Who are those authorities, anyway? Will I have to produce those documents personally at some French office? Will I need to hire a lawyer to process the paperwork?

Comment: You will probably need to consult a specialist, perhaps a lawyer or at least a consultant.

Comment: The person you will mostly talk to is a “*notaire*”. They will file the necessary paperwork with the authorities and you will pay a hefty fee (proportional to the value of the property) for the pleasure. You are not allowed to circumvent them. You can hire a lawyer if there are some complications but you and your lawyer will still need to go through a *notaire*.

Comment: This webpage https://www.notaires.fr/fr/annuaires-notaire allows to search for english speaking notaires, if that matters.